# Cookie & Privacy Policy with Google Analystics

Tags: web, google-analytics, privacy-policy, cookie-policy

I am building website and trying to put privacy and cookie policy there, only thing i store in cookies is google analystics stuff and Dark/Light theme so will "Our website uses cookies" be enought to put on website?

Answer (score 0):

It is not so much what you write to us, but the possibility of having them accepted or rejected by the user.

Those of Google Analytics are **statistical** cookies.
Those of Dark/Light theme are **preferences** cookies.

Neither of them, under normal conditions, is a **necessary** cookie. Therefore the user must be able to choose that this cookie is not installed.